# Unable to store authentication code In Nest Thermostat

Tags: ios, nest-api

Hi In my application i need to implement the Nest Thermostat.
For that i am checking the Sample code which is provided by nest for that i have registered my client after running the code successfully It Generated Authentication Code and,
I have to send this authentication code for Access Token,

but in code no where it is storing the Authentication Code and below method never executes

```
 if ([[url host] isEqualToString:[redirectURL host]])
   {
// We found the code
    if([[keyValueArray objectAtIndex:(0)] isEqualToString:@"code"]) {
                    // Send it to the delegate
        [self.delegate foundAuthorizationCode:[keyValueArray   objectAtIndex:1]];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving the authorization code.");
    }
    }
```

first condition checks but condition never goes in for storing The Authentication Token inside the loop so never goes inside

I can able to see Authentication Pin in webview that view is never getting dismissed there is code for that but for calling those methods it should execute the above condition

Where i am missing is likely either i have enter that authentication code into the device or problem in the redirect url or plz help in this.
it would be great full if some one shares the some sample redirect Urls and Process

I have seen @ Raymond George Kenned  Answers for previous question but those are not solving my Problem

Answer (score 1):

Use web base authentication and Fill the redirect url at the time of registering your client , this redirect url should not be empty on the client page,then once you run the application it will ask you to enter the login credentials there you have to enter the device login credentials(in the device you have to register) into your app then it automatically redirect and gives the authentication token then with that authentication token access token will be provided , by using that access token you can get the device details